# How can I get the id of a div inside a form using external js file

Tags: jquery-selectors

How can I access or get the div id of an element inside a form using an external js file?

Here's the example
asp file

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jsqueryms.js></script>
    <script src="myjs.js"></script>
    <body onload="initmyjs();">
    <form id="formid">
        <input type="button" id="button"/>
        <div id='dialog'>this is modal dialog</dialog>
    </form>
</head>
</html>
```

external js file

```
function initmyjs()
{
    if document.getelementby('button')!=null
       {
                document.getelementbyid('button').onlclick=function()
                {
                      $('#dialog').dialog({ modal: true, position: [902, 345], width: 400 });
                }
       }
}
```

What I want is to pop a modal dialog once the button clicked, I have no problem accessing it if the script is inside the asp page, but if I put it inside an external js file nothing happened but not script error display. I wonder if the script is correct except that I cannot map the correct element id of my div. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the content of myjs.js to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').click(function() {
        $('#dialog').dialog({ modal: true, position: [902, 345], width: 400 });
    });

    $('[name="linkComment"]').attr('href', '#').click(function() { 
        $("#dialog").dialog({ modal: true, position: [902, 345], width: 400 }); 
    });

    // Other javascript code that needs to run on page load
});

// Other javascript functions used byt he page
```

Then get rid of the `onload` attribute on the `body` tag.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thank you for your quick response. The reason why I used the unload attribute is that there are js function specific needed by the page and majority of the function is javascript codes, I just want to insert a small script that will call the pop up dialog box when user click a button/or a link tag inside a table.

Comment: This is the part of the js script from where I want to insert jquery script

Comment: You can still run the other code in this way.  See the edited answer.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that when I get back home and I will post the result right after. Thank you for your time.

Comment: 'code' links = hitlistDoc.getElementsByName('linkComment');
            links = hitlistDoc.getElementsByName('linkComment');
            for (var i=0;i<links.length;i++)
            {
                links[i].href = "#"
                links[i].onclick = function() {
                    $("#dialog").dialog({ modal: true, position: [902, 345], width: 400 });
                    });
                   
                }
 I actually test the codes and it really works, I just wonder how can I implement it on my codes given the above sample.

Comment: I figured it out, but the problem is still dialog box doesn't show, I put an alert on every click and it does pop, is there's something wrong with my codes? Here is the code, sorry I have no idea how to edit codes, so I'll just paste it on this comment box. $(document).ready(function() {
            var hitlistDoc = parent.document.getElementById("hitlist").contentDocument;
            var links=hitlistDoc.getElementsByName('linkComment');
            var i=0;
            $(links).each(function(){
                 links[i].href='#';
                  $(links[i]).click(function() {

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `.dialog()` function but maybe you need to add a call to `.show()` like this:  `$('#dialog').dialog({ modal: true, position: [902, 345], width: 400 }).show();`

Comment: Well that doesn't work either, but thanks Andrew I learn a lot from you.